# Scala Process exits but doesn't clean up threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, process, phantomjs

I am trying to run PhantomJS from within a scala application using akka actors:

```
val process = Process("phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes " + myrenderscript.js + args ...)
val result = process.run(processLogger, true).exitValue() match {
  case ExitCode.SUCCESS => Left(Success)
  case ExitCode.TIMEOUT => Right(TimeoutError)
  case ExitCode.OPEN_FAILED => Right(NetworkError)
  case _ => Right(UnknownError)        
}
```

the myrenderscript.js looks like this:

```
var version = "1.1";

var TIMEOUT = 30000,
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0,
EXIT_TIMEOUT = 2,
EXIT_OPEN_FAILED = 3;


if (phantom.args.length < 2) {
    console.log("Usage: phantomjs render.js parentUrl output [width height]");
    phantom.exit(1);
}
var url = phantom.args[0];
var output = phantom.args[1];

var width = parseInt(phantom.args[2] || 1024);
var height = parseInt(phantom.args[3] || 1024);
var clipwidth = parseInt(phantom.args[4] || 1024);
var clipheight = parseInt(phantom.args[5] || 1024);
var zoom = parseFloat(phantom.args[6] || 1.0);
var phantom_version = phantom.version.major + "." + phantom.version.minor + "." +    phantom.version.patch;
var userAgentString = "PhantomJS/" + phantom_version + " screenshot-webservice/" + version;

renderUrlToFile(url, output, width, height, clipwidth, clipheight, zoom, userAgentString, function (url, file) {
    console.log("Rendered '" + url + "' at size (" + width + "," + height + ") into '" + output + "'");
    phantom.exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    phantom = null;
});

setTimeout(function () {
    console.error("Timeout reached (" + TIMEOUT + "ms): " + url);
    phantom.exit(EXIT_TIMEOUT);
}, TIMEOUT);


function renderUrlToFile(url, file, width, height, clipwidth, clipheight, zoom,    userAgentString, callback) {
    console.log("renderUrlToFile start: " + url)
    var page = new WebPage();
    page.viewportSize = { width: width, height: height };
    page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: clipwidth, height: clipheight};
    page.settings.userAgent = userAgentString;
    page.zoomFactor = zoom;
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        console.log("renderUrlToFile open page: " + url)
        if (status !== "success") {
            console.log("Unable to render '" + url + "' (" + status + ")");
            page.release();
            page.close();
            page = null;
            phantom.exit(EXIT_OPEN_FAILED);
        } else {
            console.log("renderUrlToFile open page success and pre-render: " + url)
            page.render(file);
            console.log("renderUrlToFile open page post-render: " + url)
            page.release();
            page.close();
            page = null;
            callback(url, file);
        }
    });
}
```

prior to creating the process and after it finishes running, about 4 new threads are being created.

Each time the method that creates the process is called, new threads are created and started.  After the process is done, the threads go back to a state of monitoring.  Eventually my application takes upwards to 500+ threads (I'm capturing a large website and the internal links)

How do I get scala to clean up the threads that are created when running phantomjs?

Edit:

I've changed the scala code to do the following:

```
val process = Process("phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes " + myrenderscript.js + args ...).run(processLogger, connectInput)
val result = process.exitValue() match {
  case ExitCode.SUCCESS => Left(Success)
  case ExitCode.TIMEOUT => Right(TimeoutError)
  case ExitCode.OPEN_FAILED => Right(NetworkError)
  case _ => Right(UnknownError)        
}
process.destroy()
```

Yet still the threads live on....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out why it is not cleaning up the threads but I don't fully understand it.  So if someone posts the true answer on here, I'll vote that answer up.

The problem was I was setting the connectInput value to true.  When I set it to false, the threads get destroyed as expected.  I'm not sure as to why.

When set to true, a thread dump reveals that one of the threads was blocking the others:

```
Thread-3@2830 daemon, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
 blocks Thread-63@4131
 blocks Thread-60@4127
 blocks Thread-57@4125
 blocks Thread-54@4121
 blocks Thread-51@4103
 blocks Thread-48@4092
 blocks Thread-45@4072
 blocks Thread-42@4061
 blocks Thread-39@4054
 blocks Thread-36@4048
 blocks Thread-33@4038
 blocks Thread-30@4036
 blocks Thread-27@4008
 blocks Thread-24@3996
 blocks Thread-21@3975
 blocks Thread-18@3952
 blocks Thread-15@3939
 blocks Thread-12@3905
 blocks Thread-9@3885
 blocks Thread-6@3850
  at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java:-1)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
  at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.loop$1(BasicIO.scala:225)
  at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.transferFullyImpl(BasicIO.scala:233)
  at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.transferFully(BasicIO.scala:214)
  at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.connectToIn(BasicIO.scala:183)
  at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$$anonfun$input$1.apply(BasicIO.scala:190)
  at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$$anonfun$input$1.apply(BasicIO.scala:189)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:72)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$Spawn$$anon$1.run(ProcessImpl.scala:22)
```

I initially thought it was the process logger, but that wasn't the case.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: FWIW - When connectInput=true, the new process reads from the current process's STDIN; when you try to connect more than one, it's blocking the others since they can't read from STDIN too.

Comment: So I just ran into this problem as well. I think it's because all the other processes are attached to STDIN, and it doesn't close the thread reading from STDIN until STDIN is closed. Especially if nothing is going to STDIN. So not attaching to STDIN allows it to dispose of the threads.

Comment: some binary is leaking STDOUT or STDERR ... chk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55845231/65706