# SBT hangs waiting for orphaned subprocess to complete

Tags: scala, sbt

In my SBT (0.13.16) build, I have the following task:

```
startThing := {
  var bin_path = s"${file(".").getAbsolutePath}/bin"
  val result = s"$bin_path/start_thing".!
  if (result != 0)
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not start Thing..")
  true
}
```

And `start_thing` contains:

```
(run_subprocess &)
```

and my build hangs.

I can see that `start_thing` exits (the process table does not have it as an entry) but adding some `println`s to the task shows that it's stuck on `val result = s"$bin_path/start_thing".!`.

If I kill the `run_subprocess` process then SBT unblocks and runs normally.

In this particular case, `run_subprocess` has set up some Kubernetes port-forwarding that needs to be there in order for subsequent tests to work.

Comment: IIUC, sbt has the original Process code. Your `.!` is using sbt code, not `scala.sys.process`?

Comment: @som-snytt Good question! But, yeah, the `.!` is SBT code.

Comment: According to [SBT 1.0.0 release notes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html): *"`sbt.Process` and `sbt.ProcessExtra` are dropped. Use `scala.sys.process` instead."*

Comment: Unfortunately, using `scala.sys.process.Process(s"$bin_path/start_thing").!` hasn't helped either.  I've tried going to `1.0.x` and continue to be stymied by `java.lang.NullPointerException at okhttp3.JavaNetAuthenticator.authenticate(JavaNetAuthenticator.java:37)` (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3519).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [daemonising](http://linuxg.net/how-to-transform-a-process-into-a-daemon-in-linux-unix/) the background process like so

```
(run_subprocess >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
```

The issue could be output from `run_subprocess` still going to sbt parent as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141352/python-subprocess-calling-a-script-which-runs-a-background-process-hanging#answer-21142569).

I was able to replicate the issue in both sbt 0.13.17 and 1.0.2. Daemonising worked in both.

Comment: I am daemonizing it `(run_subprocess &)`.  I tried redirecting stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` but that hasn't helped.

Comment: I happily stand corrected! `(run_subprocess >/dev/null 2>&1 &)` has solved my problem. It makes sense, I guess, that there are processes that have hooked the file descriptors and haven't given them up, thus the launching code refuses to let go as well.  It's a bit of a shame 'cuz I like seeing the output in the build server, but I can try and tackle that another way.

Comment: is f.ng insane how-much time I lost by implementing whatever scala process , while THE 70's technology of the bash shell ONCE AGAIN saved the day ...

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of my comment, in my case the reason for the hanging was ACTUALLY the potential leaving of open STDOUT , STDERR handles in a daemon started by the script , that is OK:

```
 /usr/local/bin/minio server "$minio_data_dir" > /dev/null 2>&1 &  # and start the server
```

and NOT ok:

```
 /usr/local/bin/minio server "$minio_data_dir" 2>&1 &  # and start the server
```

So the hanging occurred randomly EVEN with the accepted answers start in the background ... 
Thus this solution needed NOT, any wrapper bash scripts ... This is how the code looked in the build.sbt

```
lazy val startLocalS3 = inputKey[Unit]("localS3")
lazy val startLocalS3Task = TaskKey[Unit]("localS3", "create local s3")
lazy val core: Project = project
   .in(file("."))
   .settings(
      name := "rfco-core",
      startLocalS3Task := {
      val cmd: Seq[String] = Seq("bash" , "-c" , "./CI/start-s3-svr.sh")
      import sys.process._
      cmd.mkString(" ").!!
     },
     fork in startLocalS3Task := true,   
     compile.in(Compile) := (compile in Compile).dependsOn((startLocalS3Task)).value
     // you might want to use Test scope ^^ here 
 )
```